# jQuery ignores HTTP request method and appends weird URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I have a web service that expects POST requests carrying a JSON string in the body. I'm trying to use this web service using jQuery, but I have two problems :

1) jQuery seems to always use the GET method, no matter what I do ;

2) jQuery seems to append weird things into the URL.

The relevant pice of my code :

```
var WEB_SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost/XXXX/';

// ...

$.post({
    url: WEB_SERVICE_URL + 'GetConfigLabels/',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // Whatever
    },
    error: function(xhr, message) {
        // Whatever
    }
});
```

The developper tools of the browser (Firefox Quantum 60.0.2) shows me a weird URL :

```
http://localhost/XXXX/GetConfigLabels/?callback=jQuery331012146934861340841_1530707758905&{}&_=1530707758906
```

While the following was expected :

```
http://localhost/XXXX/GetConfigLabels/
```

Also the HTML file is openned as a file (using file:///) through the file system, hence the use of JSONP for cross domain.

I failed to find existing questions related to this issue. What could be causing this ? Thank you !

Comment: the reason for this weird string is jsonp.

Comment: You can't post using jsonp request which is a script request.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So how could I perform a POST request using an HTML file openned from the file system (using file:///) without using JSONP ?

Comment: Open it from a local server and if necessary implement CORS in your back end

Comment: where is the web-service? on your domain or cross domain?

Comment: Create the web-service post request from server code & call that server code from ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I only needed cross domain because it seems to be required when the file is openned using file:///, but I can also have the file located on the same server as the web service and open it through a web browser, so I guess I can get rid of the JSONP thing.

Comment: Why open it using `file://` protocol? As you already see problem is solved opening on htttp

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the  **dataType** : *json* section at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests that have a callback placeholder,
>   e.g. ?callback=?, are performed using JSONP unless the request
>   includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed
>   in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error
>   is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the
>   server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org
>   for more information on proper JSON format

overrding random name of callback using **jsonpCallback** :

> jsonpCallback Type: String or Function() Specify the callback function
>   name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the
>   random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let
>   jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the
>   requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to
>   specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of
>   GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this
>   setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return
>   value of that function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.